# Not being able to show table associations in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

Currently I have a complex association in CakePHP that I'm not being able to solve out.

I have these models:

- List (id, name)
- Referrals (id, name, email)
- List_Users (join_table: id, referral_id, user_id)
- Users (id, name, email).

The relationships are:

- Lists <- HABTM -> Lists_Users <- HABTM -> Users
- Referrals belongsto Lists
- Lists hasMany Referrals

*Users are registered users, referrals are just friends that they recommend to this list. The system contains many different lists.

What I'm trying to do is setup a **showList** function in Lists controller to show up all Users and Referrals linked to this list. I have tried using this as the controller at first, but no success:

```
function showList() {
    $this->List->recursive = 2;
    $users->List->User->find('all');
    $referrals->List->Referral->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('users','referral'));
    $this->set('listas', $this->paginate());
}
```

How can I possibly make this association work and show all data needed?

Comment: You're not assigning results of your `find`s to variables. Is this a mistake in question, or in your code?

Comment: It was a mistake. I have managed to fix the problem, just need to wait 8h after question being posted to post the reply with the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my own head, it seems I found the awnser to my own question! The correct function would be:

```
function showList($id = null) {
    $this->List->recursive = 0;
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    else {
    $this->set('list', $this->List->read(null, $id));
    $this->set('users', $this->List->User->find('all',
        array(
            'fields' => array('id','name', 'email'),
            'order' => 'name ASC'  
            )
        ));
    $this->set('referrals', $this->List->Referral->find('all',
        array(
            'fields' => array('id','name', 'email'),
            'order' => 'name ASC'  
            )
        ));
    }
    $this->set('lists', $this->paginate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `List_Users` model should be `ListsUsers` (plural lists, and camel-case, not underscore.)